# Getting dysmutil malloc error when using nstask Tool Exited with code 134

Tags: xcode, malloc, nstask, xbuild, dsymutil

This is the code i am using to generate ios build using nstask in my cocoa app.

```
NSTask *task=[[NSTask alloc]init];
task.launchPath=@"/library/Frameworks/Mono.Framework/Commands/xbuild";
task.arguments= @[@"/p:Configuration=Release",@"/p:Platform=iPhone",@"/p:BuildIpa=false",@"/target:Build",@"/Users/xyz/Projects/SimpleDemo/SimpleDemo.sln"];
NSPipe *pipe=[[NSPipe alloc]init];
[task setStandardOutput:pipe];
NSFileHandle *outputFileHandle;
outputFileHandle = [[NSFileHandle alloc]init];
outputFileHandle=[pipe fileHandleForReading];

[outputFileHandle waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification object:outputFileHandle queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification){

    NSData *output = [outputFileHandle availableData];
    NSString *outStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:output encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",outStr);

    [outputFileHandle waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify];

}];
@try {
    [task launch];
    [task waitUntilExit];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"%@",[exception callStackSymbols]);

}
@finally {

}
```

i am getting this error while running the code

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iO     S.Common.targets: error : Tool exited with code: 134. Output:         warning: (armv7)  could not find object file symbol for symbol _xamarin_register_modules
warning: (armv7)  could not find object file symbol for symbol _xamarin_register_assemblies
warning: (armv7)  could not find object file symbol for symbol _xamarin_setup
warning: (armv7)  could not find object file symbol for symbol _main
warning: (armv7)  could not find object file symbol for symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MonoTouchAppDelegate
warning: (armv7)  could not find object file symbol for symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_MonoTouchAppDelegate

dsymutil(6764,0x7fff78631000) malloc: *** error for object 0x6000000fb400: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

In this build process error comes after .app generation means there is problem after .app generation.

Note:if i run this command using terminal then it works without any error and .ipa gets generated.Problem is only when i use nstask to run this command.

i am using el capitan and xcode 7.1.1.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure whether you have solved the same issue to me or not, here is a related topic here in Apple Forums: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18311

Answer (score 0):

As per the suggestion from @Itachi, issue is regarding the MallocNanoZone being enabled. This needs to be removed from the environment of NSTask explicitly.

Here is the code which I got from [IPABuddy](https://github.com/darkcl/IPABuddy/commit/c619a5ef5e89839f9b631543ff86e5122a13344c)

```
        NSTask *task=[[NSTask alloc]init];

        NSMutableDictionary *theEnvironment = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo].environment mutableCopy];
        if (theEnvironment[@"MallocNanoZone"])
        {
            [theEnvironment removeObjectForKey:@"MallocNanoZone"];
        }

        task.environment = theEnvironment;
```

Hope this helps.